# Cannot validate part of string in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Working on a booking project; I want to check if the seat that the user has inputted is already taken on the database; if it has, then the query to add the booking to the database shouldn't be executed. Otherwise, if it hasn't been taken, then the query can be executed. However, at the moment, the data is inserting into the database but I'm also getting a 'Seat Taken' message even though the seat hasn't already been taken in the database. The seats field in my flights_booked database can contain comma separated values.

```
<?PHP 

$database = 'users';

$db_found = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $database );

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($db_found) {
    
    $seat = "SELECT * FROM flights_booked WHERE Seats LIKE '%$_POST[seats]%'";
    
    $run = mysqli_query($conn, $seat);
    
    if($run) {
        echo "Seat taken";
        
    } else {
        echo 'No';
    }
    
    
}

$mysql = "insert into flights_booked (User_ID, Flight_ID, Infants, Children, Adults, Seats, Dietary_Requirements, Requirement) values('$ID', '$_POST[flight]', '".addslashes($_POST['infants'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['children'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['adults'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['seats'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['dietary-requirement'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['requirement'])."')";

$run = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        
        if($run) {
            echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
    
        
        
}

?>
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: You're just verifying if the query ran, not if there are any results. `Returns false on failure. For successful queries which produce a result set, such as SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN, mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries, mysqli_query() will return true.` https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Ans you should put the insert query in the if bloc otherwise code will always be executed